# how track website unique visitors excluding 404! page using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, unique, tracking, visitor-pattern

I want to track my website visitor using codeigniter. but I dont want to track 404! pages e,g if a user put controller ,method or parameter into website domain then website show 404 page so this will not track. Also I want to check user activities if user is loggedin.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Simply apply [google analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) to your `layout_view` and see what you want and don't put this tracker into 404 page view. Done

Comment: I need it to store into my db,for future audit the site.

Comment: Google Analytics also provides API to access those data, other than only unique visitors, there are various information provided, you can take benefit of it,

Comment: You may use browser fingerprinting to track unique users

Comment: I expect a some programmatically codes, However thanks @Sandeep J Patel

Comment: @gsali try something like this https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to track a unique visitor, you can get a visitor's `IP addresses` and can store them in the database. If any user logging in then you can make an entry after the successful login of the user. Hope this can solve your problem

Comment: Thanks! it is helpful.